# Change default indentation step for "Ctrl+M" shortcut (Word)?

Tags: microsoft-word

On **Word**, when I press `Ctrl+M` to increase paragraph's indentation, it increases indentation by `1 inch`. What I need to do is to change the default indentation step (`1 inch`) every time I press `Ctrl+M` to be some other value (e.g. `0.75 inch` instead of `1 inch`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way:

- Select the entire document with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
- In the Home pane, Paragraph group, click the little "paragraph Settings"
  icon at the bottom-right of the group
- In the "Indents and Spacing" tab, click the "Tabs..." button at the bottom-left
- Change the value below "Default tab stops:"
- Click OK.

[image]